# ASP.NET Core 6.0+: How to get the current (case-sensitive) IIS Website Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get the name of my ASP.NET 6 app hosted in IIS. What I need is exactly this name with proper casing:

[image]

In .NET Framework 4.8, this name was provided by [HttpRequest.ApplicationPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Web.HttpRequest.ApplicationPath?view=netframework-4.8) and it was returned with proper casing (as configured in IIS, not as in the coming request's URL). However, it doesn't exist in .NET 6.

I tried:

- `HttpContext.Request.PathBase`, but it returns the path exactly as in the requesting URL, not as in the IIS
- injecting `IServerAddressesFeature` and `IWebHostEnvironment`, but none of them contains the name from IIS with correct casing
- `IServerAddressesFeature`, but also didn't find anything relevant here
- getting server variables: `IServerVariablesFeature serverVars = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>()` and then the IIS Site name: `string iis_version = serverVars["INSTANCE_NAME"]` (see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables)), but it returns the app name in capital letters (`MYSITE.WEB`)

Does anyone know how to get this site's name as configured in IIS (with proper casing)?

Comment: **Exactly** how are you running your ASP.NET Core project under/with IIS? There are huge differences between running Kestrel behind ARR compared to running under ANCM (`AspNetCoreModuleV2`) in-proc within `w3wp.exe` or out-of-process mode.

Comment: I host it with IIS using `InProcess` mode within `w3wp.exe`

Comment: What is the value of the `APPL_MD_PATH` server-variable?

Comment: @Dai this one looks promising! It returns `"/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MySite.Web"`, so the part after the last slash seems to be what I need :)

Comment: I'm almost done writing my answer.

Comment: BTW, I'm not seeing `INSTANCE_NAME` anywhere at my end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR:

- Use the `APPL_MD_PATH` server-variable.

  - This contains the IIS Metabase Application Path string. (AFAIK, "MD" stands for "Meta-database").
  - *Quoteth the docs*:

    > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
    >
    > "`APPL_MD_PATH` - Retrieves the metabase path of the application."

Like so:

```
// This code assumes HttpContext is available, such as in a Middleware method or `Controller` subclass.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

String? iisMetabasePath = httpContext.GetServerVariable("APPL_MD_PATH");

// or (long-form):

String? iisMetabasePath = HttpContextServerVariableExtensions.GetServerVariable( httpContext, "APPL_MD_PATH" );
```

Then just trim-off the `/LM/W3SVC/` part.

Note that when you run your code outside of IIS, such as with ASP.NET Core's development server, all IIS-specific data, like `"APPL_MD_PATH"` won't be available, so make sure you're handling that case too.

---

### Original research: *What happened to `ApplicationRoot`?*

Time to [bust-out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tdyU_gW6WE) ILSpy...

1. `HttpRequest.ApplicationPath` is `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`.
2. `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` is `VirtualPath.GetVirtualPathStringNoTrailingSlash(HttpRuntime._theRuntime._appDomainAppVPath)`.
3. `HttpRuntime._theRuntime._appDomainAppVPath` is set in `HttpRuntime.Init()`.
4. `HttpRuntime.Init()` sets `_appDomainAppVPath` from `HttpRuntime.GetAppDomainString(".appVPath"))`.

   - "AppDomain Strings" are small *serializable* scalar [values that are associated with each `AppDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.setdata?view=netframework-4.8).
   - Generally speaking, ASP.NET in .NET Framework (aka `System.Web`) creates a new `AppDomain` for each *Application Scope* in IIS.
   - And of course, AppDomains [no-longer exist in .NET Core and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable).
   - So let's find out where the `String` value for `".appVPath"` comes from...
5. `System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager::PopulateDomainBindings` sets `dict.Add(".appVPath", appVPath.VirtualPathString)`

   - "domain bindings" in this context refers to *AppDomain bindings*: nothing at all to do with DNS domain-names or `Host` header bindings in IIS. Yay for overloaded terminology.
6. `PopulateDomainBindings` is called by `System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager::CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment`.

   - And it gets `virtualPath: VirtualPath.Create(appHost.GetVirtualPath())`.
7. `appHost.GetVirtualPath()` is `IApplicationHost.GetVirtualPath()`.

   - There are 2 in-box implementations: `System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIApplicationHost` and `System.Web.Hosting.SimpleApplicationHost`. We're interested in `ISAPIApplicationHost`.
8. `ISAPIApplicationHost` gets its virtualPath from the runtime argument to `String appId` and `String appPath` in the `IAppManagerAppDomainFactory.Create` method.

   - And `IAppManagerAppDomainFactory` is a COM interface used directly by IIS.

     - The plot thickens...
9. At this point I got lost trawling [through the legacy IIS 6 ISAPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525881(v=vs.90)), looking for traces of the original COM definition of `IAppManagerAppDomainFactory` but came up empty-handed.

   - It's probably handled by `webengine4.dll` which is a native DLL and I don't have the time to bust-out Ghidra right now...
   - I did notice that the ISAPI request [entrypoint method `HttpExtensionProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525010(v=vs.90)) (and its [`LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525658(v=vs.90))) *do not* contain the IIS Application Scope `AppId` or Virtual Path, which surprised me - but most importantly: this suggests the value must likely come from the `GetServerVariable` or `ServerSupportFunction` callbacks....
   - However that's likely a waste of time anyway IIS 6 is *not* IIS7+ and IIS7+'s interfaces are no-longer called "ISAPI" but instead called just "IIS Native-Code API" (that's the most plain and boring API name I've seen in a while...).
10. So, starting with the *"IIS Native-Code API"* documentation [I quickly found the `IWpfApplicationInfoUtil::GetApplicationPropertiesFromAppId` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-development-reference/native-code-api-reference/iwpfapplicationinfoutil-getapplicationpropertiesfromappid-method) (here "WPF" means "[Worker Process Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-development-reference/native-code-api-reference/worker-process-framework-api-reference)", and is entirely unrelated to the *other* UI-related WPF).

    - I also found the same data exposed [via the `IMetadataInfo.GetMetaPath()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-development-reference/native-code-api-reference/imetadatainfo-getmetapath-method) (which returns a string of the form `"LM/WEBROOT/AppHost/{SiteId}"`).
    - So how does an application get a `IWpfApplicationInfoUtil` interface reference?

      - `IWorkerProcessFramework->GetWpfInterface(WPF_APPLICATION_INFO_UTIL_ID)->GetApplicationPropertiesFromAppId`

        - So how do you get `IWorkerProcessFramework`?

          - [It's passed as a parameter into your `w3wp.exe` worker DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-development-reference/native-code-api-reference/pfn-get-protocol-manager-function).
          - So let's see what `AspNetCoreModuleV2` does...
11. [Actually `AspNetCoreModuleV2` uses IIS's `IHttpApplication`, *derp*](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2/InProcessRequestHandler/dllmain.cpp).

    - [`IHttpApplication` exposes `GetAppConfigPath()` which also returns a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/smooth-streaming-client/ihttpapplication-getapplicationid-method) of the form `/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/{Site Name}`.
    - [ASP.NET Core seems to use it in a few places](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/search?q=GetAppConfigPath).
12. At this point I gave up as it's now 6:20am, but that was a fun dive!

Comment: wow, thanks for that answer and the historical context :) I'm only wondering whether I can rather get the value of `APPL_MD_PATH` and then take only the part after the last slash as IIS Site name. In my case, `APPL_MD_PATH` contains `/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MySite.Web`, where only `MySite.Web` is the actual Site name present in the URL.